# How to refer to multiple images in a folder in Assets in a ForEach loop?

Tags: swiftui

Say I have multiple images in a folder in Assets and I would like to put them in a ForEach loop. And there are too many to manually type the image names into an array. Is there a way to generate such an array with code?

```
ForeEach(1…30) { item in
    Image (“Folder\(image name)”)
}
```

Big TIA from a newbie

Comment: Folder in Assets means nothing in run-time - it is just for structuring in Xcode, the compiled Assets is flat. If you want to access per folder, move folder resources into app bundle manually and access it via Bundle class API directly.

Comment: adding to @Asperi: you can also just keep the images in your Assets folder (folder's name will be ignored), but you don't need to include the folder name in the Image access. If the images are named "image 1", "image 2" ... you can just display them via `Image("image \(item)")` in the ForEach loop.